# Android intentService Guidance

Tags: java, android, intentservice, aide

After spending near a full week copying and pasting about every example online, I have come to realise that I just don't understand serviceIntent.

I understand the theory(I think), it's just it never works for me when I try. I have stripped my existing code, leaving only what's necessary to ask this question, using 'println' to demonstrate a working example or not. Could you guys tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks.

If it's important, I am only using AIDE. I have checked if AIDE has limitations in regards to intentservices but have found nothing to say not.

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.mycompany.rns;

imports are listed here...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public class MyService extends IntentService {

        public MyService(){
            super("MyService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            system.out.println("At fucking last!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent k = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(k);
    }
}
```

MANIFEST.XML

```
</activity>
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

Comment: android:name=".My Service" !! what is that space doing here?  between My and Service ..

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo ;)

Comment: If you have a good confrontational computer, use Android Studio instead.

Comment: try to move the MyService class in another separated class from the MainActivityClass

Comment: I'm actually away from home for awhile, so I downloaded AIDE in order to code away from home....is AIDE the problem? And what do you mean by confrontational computer?

Comment: Ahmed Ewiss - I appologise for my newbieness, do you mean create another .java file to house my service class?

Comment: @user4163554  yes .

Comment: @user4163554 Confrontational computer by means system requirements that meets android studio requirements. Look at here https://imgur.com/m3mMYZl

Comment: Give me a moment, I'll just make the adjustment.

Comment: @Ahmed Ewiss - OMFG!! Thankyou sir, if I could hug you I would. This is a monumental leap for me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ahmed Ewiss has given a correct answer, but not created an answer that I can accept, using his advice, this is for everyone else as a simple template they can use...

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.mycompany.rns;

imports are listed here...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent k = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(k);
    }
}
```

MYSERVICE.JAVA

```
package com.mycompany.rns;

imports are listed here...

public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService(){
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        system.out.println("At fucking last!");
    }
}
```

MAIN.XML

```
</activity>
<service
     android:name=".MyService"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

The working solution was to seperate the MainActivity.java file from the Service.java file. class file.